# Proper use of "would rather... than" in this sentence

Tags: idioms, adverbs, would-rather

I want to use "would rather... than" to show a comparison like this:

```
I'd rather buy Phone-1 than buy Phone-2.
```

I learned about it from Oxford Dictionary:

> **would rather… (than)** - (usually reduced to ’d rather) would prefer
>
> Example: to She'd rather die than give a speech.

But as you can see, both sides have a different verb (`die` and `give`) but in my case it is same, i.e., `buy`.

Alternatively, I found another definition which seems slightly easy to me:

> **rather than** - ​instead of somebody/something
>
> I think I'll have a cold drink rather than coffee.

So my sentence would become:

```
I'd buy Phone-1 rather than Phone-2.
```

Which seems correct to me because in definition, there are different words (`cold drink` and `coffee`). And similarly, in my sentence (`Phone-1` and `Phone-2`). But still I want to learn the use of first definition.

So I'm not sure if it's correct or not. So is it okay to use it like this or incorrect?

Comment: Note that as well as "deleting" predictably repeated *verbs*, we can also delete other elements. So with *I'd rather have a cold drink than **have a hot drink*** we can discard the repeated verb as *I'd rather have a cold drink than **a hot drink***, but we can also delete the repeated noun *I'd rather have a cold drink than **hot***. But in that context we can't delete *only* the noun element - *I'd rather have a cold drink than **have [a] hot*** is definitely not acceptable to *this* native speaker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can say 'I'd buy Phone-1 rather than Phone-2', but it would be more usual to say 'I'd rather buy Phone-1 than Phone-2' *without repeating the verb.*

Comment: So my first example was okay but I just have to remove repeated verb right?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant.